# Browscap.ini throwing an error when loading PHP (command line - PHP_CLI)

Tags: cron, syntax-error, php, browscap

I have a cronjob that summarize browser statistics. This cronjob loads data and then use the get_browser() PHP function to parse the browser information.

Here's what I did:

```
cd /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
me@ubutnu:/etc/php5/cli/conf.d$ sudo wget http://browsers.garykeith.com/stream.asp?Lite_PHP_BrowsCapINI -O browscap.ini
2011-09-30 15:14:18 (890 KB/s) - `browscap.ini' saved [185384/185384]
```

Then the cronjob run:

```
php /usr/local/cron/summarizeStats.php --option=browserStats --date=yesterday
```

and I get this error:

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ']' in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/browscap.ini on line 51
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I just downloaded the latest browsecap file for php, and it is over 20,000 lines, so if it is saying unexpected $end at line 51, then the file you have is incomplete.  Unexpected $end means that php encountered the end of a file when it wasn't expecting to.  Did you download the browsecap file that is PHP compatible?  Here is a link to the [latest php browsecap.ini](http://browsers.garykeith.com/stream.asp?PHP_BrowsCapINI)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is seemingly right now an error with those browsecap files. They seem to contain unescaped semicolons ";" in the browser spec. You can fix that using this little script:

```
<?php
$browsecap = file('browscap.ini');
foreach( $browsecap as &$row )
    if ( $row[ 0 ] == '[' )
        $row = str_replace( ';', '\\;', $row );

file_put_contents( 'fixed_browscap.ini', $browsecap );
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. IEs where not recognized. I replaced the semicolons and ticks with asterisks inside my shell script and it worked again. Example: `sed  -e '/^\[/ s/;/*/g' /etc/php5/apache2/browscap_orig.ini > /etc/php5/apache2/browscap.ini

sed  -i "/^\[/ s/'/*/g"  /etc/php5/apache2/browscap.ini`

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but there are still problems with using file without modifications. I'm using following script  to download and change browscap.ini so it can work on my server.

```
#!/bin/sh
url="http://browscap.org/stream?q=PHP_BrowsCapINI"
curl -L -o browscap.ini ${url}
sed -I "" -E 's/;/\\;/g' browscap.ini
sed -I "" -E 's/[\\;]{40}/;;;/g' browscap.ini
sed -I "" -E "s/\'/\\\'/g" browscap.ini
mv browscap.ini /usr/local/etc/php/browscap.ini
```

Explanation

- 1st sed is escaping every `;` with `\'`
- 2nd sed is returning comments to previous state (slow), replacing just 4 or 5 semicolons will cause error because there is some section with string like this `(;;;;)`. This could be optimised with something like `^\;` in search part, and just single `;` in replace part, need to test that before I put
- 3rd sed is escaping single quote used in "Let's encrypt..." sections and in couple other places like this `'*'`

Don't forget to adjust your browscap.ini finial destination. Also there is no need for Apache or PHP restart after update, so put this script somewhere and setup cron job.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can be used to escape the semi-colon like so:

```
sed 's/;/\\\;/g' browscap.ini > browscap_escape.ini
```

This will catch all the comments as well but you could use `sed` again to catch those.

As described here [github.com/browscap/browscap/issues/119](https://github.com/browscap/browscap/issues/119#issuecomment-35433447)